# Tensorflow-Probability. - Saving and restoring checkpoints for bayesian neural network

Tags: tensorflow, probability, bayesian, checkpoint

I'd been looking at the Tensorflow Probability library and trying to modify the example in [bayesian network example](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/bayesian_neural_network.py), hoping that I can save checkpoints and then restore them. I first started trying to use tf.train.Checkpoint but, although, I was not getting any error, neither when saving nor when restoring, didnt seem to restart the training from the previous checkpoint as the accuracy was completely different value. 
I then tried using tf.keras.models.model.save, which again does save a file, but when trying to restore, I get the error: ValueError: Unknown layer: Conv2DFlipout when it is trying to deserialise the layer. 
To be honest I dont know which way to go now, if somebody could point me to the right direction. 
Thanks!
Giovanna

This is what I have so far to restore:

```
 if FLAGS.architecture == "resnet":
    model_fn = bayesian_resnet.bayesian_resnet
else:
    model_fn = bayesian_vgg.bayesian_vgg

model = model_fn(
  IMAGE_SHAPE,
  num_classes=4,
  kernel_posterior_scale_mean=FLAGS.kernel_posterior_scale_mean,
  kernel_posterior_scale_constraint=FLAGS.kernel_posterior_scale_constraint)
print(images)

#check if saved checkpoint exists
exists = os.path.isfile(FLAGS.model_dir+"checkpoint.hdf5")
if exists:
  model = tf.keras.models.load_model(FLAGS.model_dir+"checkpoint.hdf5") 

logits = model(images)
labels_distribution = tfd.Categorical(logits=logits)

# Perform KL annealing. The optimal number of annealing steps
# depends on the dataset and architecture.
t = tf.Variable(0.0)
#kl_regularizer = t / (FLAGS.kl_annealing * len(x_train) / FLAGS.batch_size)
...
```